# Vector version of Magento Stack Exchange logo

Tags: feature-request, design

Wondering if it's possible to get a vector version of the logo.  Want to use it in my list of social links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logo on the Stack Exchange is actually a vector (SVG), I've quickly cropped it out the sprite so if you don't receive an official version you should be able to edit this to what you want:

http://codepen.io/BenCrook/pen/KaBgVY?editors=1000

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a friggin BEAST.  I'd actually love to get just the glyph though without "Magento" in it....?

Comment: @kalenjordan Check the codepen again ;)